# Fedena Pro 3.0 Rake db:create on ubuntu 14.04 Create Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, fedena

I am Installing Fedena 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. When give this command Rake db:create I get the following error, pls help.

I searched the solution on google a lot but none helped.

My gem list is:

***** LOCAL GEMS *****

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
bundler (1.9.4)
daemons (1.1.9)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
hoe (3.13.1)
i18n (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
mini_portile (0.6.1)
multi_json (1.10.1)
passenger (5.0.6)
prawn (0.6.3)
prawn-core (0.6.3)
prawn-format (0.2.3)
prawn-layout (0.3.2)
prawn-security (0.1.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rspec (3.2.0)
rspec-core (3.2.3)
rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
rspec-support (3.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
rush (0.6.8)
session (3.2.0)
simpleconsole (0.1.1)
task (0.0.1)
test-unit (1.2.3)
```

**The Errors I get:**

```
# rake db:create --trace
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /home/tareen/ansi)
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- spec/rake/spectask
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/tareen/ansi/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `block in load_with_new_constant_marking'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/tareen/ansi/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

pls help me.

Comment: I error gone now I downgraded rspec to 1.2.9 and now I just get the follwoing error

rake db:create
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

Comment: try `gem update rake`

Comment: updated rake but getting errors again

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:268:in `=='
.
.
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedena requires Ruby 1.8.7, *specifically*. Installations of Fedena on any other versions of ruby will fail. These are the following versions of software required:

- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rubygems 1.3.7
- Rails 2.3.5

You can use the following to confirm the versions. For Ruby, run `ruby -v`. For Rubygems, run `gem -v` and for rails, you can use the `rails -v` command,  or `gem list | grep rails`.

Your problem stems from the fact that Ruby 1.8.* was removed from the official Ubuntu 14.04 repositories and your installation of Rails is downloading 1.9.1 as a dependency.

To make this easier for you, I invite you to setup a new server and run the auto-installer of Fedena 2.3 [here](http://n3rve.com/fedena-auto-installer-ubuntu-14-04) which will install the basic libraries required after which you should install the additional gems above and your installation should work properly.

Comment: thanks dear Auto Installer worked for 2.3 now trying 3.0 hope it will work too.

Comment: @Naveed If 2.3 runs fine, 3.0 will work as well. You just need to get the dependencies in order. Good luck :)

Comment: I get an error of no such file --nokogiri in 3.0 even its there in gem list.
nokogiri 1.6.1

Comment: Run `gem uninstall nokogiri -Iax` then `gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.10`.

Comment: one problem solved another raised

rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Spec::Rake::SpecTask:0x7f996f809340>

Comment: updated gems to rubygems-update 1.6.2 and now I get the error

rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String

Comment: Since we resolved the error above which was the main question here, I think this discussion should be moved elsewhere. You can contact me through the blog to help you.

Comment: After you've read this, I'm going to ask that the comments here be cleared.